# Android - animate view from RelativeLayout to sibling Relativeayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-relativelayout

My `Activity` has a `RelativeLayout` as it's main view with the id `parent`. Within this I have two `RelativeLayouts`, `child1` and `child2`.

I want to animate an `ImageView` from `child2 RelativeLayout` to `child1`. I don't want the image to disappear in `child2` to then suddenly appear in `child1`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/child1"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/child2">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I can't find anyway of doing this without using `addView` and `removeView`. If I do this though, the `ImageView` will just appear in `child1`, and I won't be able to animate it smoothly.

I have the idea of the following possible way but it feels like a real long winded hack.

- finding the `x` and `y` of the `ImageView`
- adding a duplicate view in `parent`
- removing the original from `child2`
- animate the duplicate in `parent` to the correct position in `child1` (which will require potentially difficult calculations)
- add the original view in `child1` which is underneath the duplicate view
- remove the duplicate view

Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

For a simple way you can try like this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/child1>

       <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

       </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/child2">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility:gone/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and in Java when button is pressed for example, just add drawable to "image2", set visible "image2" and hide "image1".

Comment: But that will just make one image appear and the other disappear. I need an animation transition from one to the next